# How can you tell if a table in DB2 has a Primary Key?

Tags: db2, primary-key

We are using a tool that requires specific tables in our DB2 database to have a Primary Key defined.

Is there a way using a select statement on the DB to see if a given table has one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Disclaimer: I do not know DB2.

I simply googled these with "db2 table definition".

[Source:](http://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/480240-view-db2-table-definitions-qmf#post2171771)

```
SELECT * 
FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES TAB,SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS COL 
WHERE TAB.CREATOR = COL.TBCREATOR 
AND TAB.CREATOR = 'xxxx' 
AND TAB.NAME = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx' 
AND TAB.NAME = COL.TBNAME 
AND TAB.TYPE = 'V' ( OR 'T' ) 
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

[Source:](http://dbaspot.com/db2-udb/267179-list-all-table-primary-key.html)

```
SELECT * FROM syscat.tabconst WHERE type = 'P';
```

Comment: TAB.TYPE = 'V' will give you views, which I believe you do not want.  Use TAB.TYPE='T' for tables.

Answer (score 8):

you can do a `db2look`, which will give you the ddls for the table.

```
db2look -d db_name -e -x -z schema_name -t table_name
```

Comment: Welcome to dba.se and thanks for this helpful answer - I hope you don't mind my formatting edit?

Comment: @JackDouglas -- thanks for those edits, looks pretty readable now

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the easiest option, since a primary key is supported by a matching index:

```
select COLNAMES from SYSIBM.SYSINDEXES where tbname = 'TABLE' and uniquerule = 'P';
```

You can also query the columns catalog table:

```
select NAME from SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS where tbname = 'TABLE' and keyseq > 0 order by keyseq;
```

Comment: The primary key is _not_ an index (although it is supported by one).

Answer (score 0):

1. SYSCAT.INDEXES.UNIQUERULE  ( If UNIQUERULE is P then primary Key )
2. SYSCAT.TABCONST.TYPE       ( if Type is P then Primary Key Constraint )